# Activity not being created

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, oncreate

I'm trying to show a confirmation screen once a fall is detected. If the fall is detected, i call 'showConfirmation', which follows the following flow:

Method called when fall is detected:

```
public void showConfirmation(Context context, String data) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CaidaActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("data", data);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Activity to show:

```
public class CaidaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("data");
        actualizarTextos(R.string.caida_texto, R.string.caida_aceptar, R.string.caida_cancelar);
        playSonido();
        playVibracion();
        startContador();
    }
...
```

I've tried the very basic print("here") method of debugging and turns out method 'onCreate' is never called in the firt place. Anyone knows why?

Comment: give your exact error to find the exact error occurred on the code.

Comment: did you set this in your activity? **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)**

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined your activity in the manifest file? If so, then the error may be hidden in the fall check.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did, I tested on multiple devices and in some the activity shows and others doesnt, could it be just bugged because of the android version?

Comment: One thing before that, can you show part of your code where you wrote to open CaidaActivity?